# How mock a method with one parameter with moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I'm not familiar with mocking. I'd like test if my method GetById return me an object User with an Id. Below the code, I'd like test if the GetById(10) return me an User with id = 10.

I set the moq (I hope it's correct) but how execute the moq ?

Thanks,

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMoq()
{
    var userMock = new Mock<IUsers>();
    userMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10)).Returns(new User());

    //After ?
    new Users().GetById(10);
}

public interface IUsers
{
    IUser GetById();
}

public IUser GetById(int id)
{
    using (var context = ....)
    {
        //code here

        //return user here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `UsersDb` class refers the `IUsers`? Or it implements `IUsers` interface?

Comment: Sorry typo error corrected. Methods defined in IUsers return IUser or in some case for GetList() a List<IUser>

Comment: I don't get it. Can you not do something like userMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10)).Returns(new User{Id = 10});?

Comment: btw, there's another typo: `IUser GetByUd()` <- missing parameter

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to test. The implementation of `IUsers#GetById(int)` which effectively is implemented in `Users#GetById(int)`? Then you don't need to mock it, you need to call it and check the result.

Comment: (continuation) If your `Users#GetById(int)` is supposed to call `IUser#GetById(int)` then you need to mock `IUser#GetById(int)`(as you've shown already in `MyMoq` method) and pass `userMock.Object` to `Users` instance. Please let me know if that's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as I said in comments, it's not clear for me what code you're trying to test. I see two options here.
1) The `Users` class implements `IUsers` interface and your intention is to test implementation of `GetById(int)` method.
In such case you do NOT need to mock the 'Users#GetById(id)' method, you just need to call it and check the result.
The code should look similar to:

```
interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; }
}
class User : IUser
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
}

interface IUsers
{
    IUser GetById(int id);
}
class Users : IUser
{
    public IUser GetById(int id)
    {
        // TODO: make call db call
        // TODO: parse the result
        // TODO: and return new User instance with all the data from db
        return new User{ Id = id };
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyMoq()
{   
    // TODO: prepare/mock database. That's whole another story.

    var users = new Users();

    // act
    var user = users.GetById(10);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(10, user.Id);
}
```

2) Your `Users#GetById(int)` method is supposed to call the `IUsers#GetById(int)` and return the result. In such case you need to create mock of `IUsers`(as you've shown in question) and pass it to `Users`. The code should be(sorry for possible duplication):

```
interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; }
}
class User : IUser
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
}

interface IUsers
{
    IUser GetById(int id);
}
class Users : IUser
{
    private readonly IUser _users;
    public Users(IUser users)
    {
        _users = users;
    }

    public IUser GetById(int id)
    {
        // next line of code is to be tested in unit test
        return _users.GetById(id);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyMoq()
{   
    var usersMock = new Mock<IUsers>();
    usersMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10)).Returns(new User());

    var users = new Users(usersMock.Object);

    // act
    var user = users.GetById(10);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(10, user.Id);
}
```

p.s. Could be useful to take a look at [moq tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) and [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) book, `Part 2 - Core techniques`(page 47) - stubs, mocks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite sure what you want to test. You also has Mock class with some methods that you don't describe.

However, answering your question about mocking. Consider this class:

```
public class MyMoq : IUsers
{
  private readonly Mock<IUsers> userMock;
  public MyMoq(Mock<IUsers> userMock){
    this.userMock = userMock;
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public IUser GetById()
  {
      userMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10)).Returns(new User());

      //After ?
      return new UsersDb().GetById(10);
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
MyMoq moq = new MyMoq(new Mock<IUsers>());
User u = moq.GetById();
```

My assumption in this example is `Mock<IUsers>` is a repository and `MyMoq` is a service class. Also, `IUser` is an Entity Interface, and `IUsers` is a service interface.

Comment: There is no Assert or something ? In the u the Id is 0 and not 10 normal ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, I mick GetById(10), the object returned by the userMock.Object.GetById(10); does not have an Id = 5 ?

Comment: This is the folly of unit testing.  This test that is essentially useless.  It will always return a new user when GetById = 10.  What exactly does that test?

Answer (score 0):

To test `userMock.Object` should return the actual mocked `IUsers` object.

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUsers>();
userMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10)).Returns(new User());

var mockobject = userMock.Object;

//Returns your mocked new User() instance
var newUserObject = mockobject.GetById(10);
```

In the above code, `newUserObject` has only created a new instance of `User`.
To test your `GetById` method, you need to call it again and Assert.

```
Assert.AreEqual(newUserObject.GetById(20).ID, 20);  //Assume User has a property ID
```

***Suggestion:*** It should be possible to have a better way to create the `User` instance.

Comment: @Kris-I : Does this help, do you have any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

GetById should be in it's own class (probably called Users) if that is what is being tested. Users could then accept a context in the constructor. Then mock this context to return stubbed data.

So in summary

Class Users implementing IUsers
Users has a constructor with parameter IContext (or whatever it would be called here)
Test class would mock IContext but not IUsers.
Call users.GetById and check the output is correct.

The way you would set up your context depends on what type of context it is, but see https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84.